# performance of javascript across iframe boundary

Tags: javascript, performance, iframe, browser

JavaScript codes in the main html document can access codes and data in its iframes an vice versa, if not blocked by the browser. However, what about the performance? Are there performance penalties across iframe boundary?

I make a simple test and find that it depends on browsers:

- chrome 28: calling functions in a iframe from the main document is as fast as calling functions in the main document.
- firefox 23: calling functions in a iframe is much slower (~6x).
- IE 11 preview: calling functions in a iframe is much slower (~3.5x), but better than firefox.

I want to known what makes these difference? Do the codes in the main document and iframes run in a same JavaScript VM?

Can we expect that firefox and IE reduce or even eliminate these performance penalties in the near future?

My test code is as follow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Calc in iframe</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="testCalcIFrame()">testCalcIFrame</button>
    <button onclick="testCalc()">testCalc</button>
    <button onclick="iwin.testCalcAllIframe()">testCalcAllIframe</button>
    <iframe id="iframe" style="display:none;"></iframe>
    <script>
        var iwin = document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow;
        iwin.document.open('text/html');
        iwin.document.close();        

        //Copy functions calc() and testCalcAllIframe() into the iframe.
        iwin.eval(calc.toString());
        iwin.eval(testCalcAllIframe.toString());

        var icalc = iwin.calc;

        var arrLength = 1000 * 1000;

        var arr = new Array(arrLength);
        for (var i = 0; i < arrLength; i++)
            arr[i] = i;

        function calc() {
            var n = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                n += Math.round(arguments[i] / 3);
            }
            return n;
        }

        //test calling calc() in the main document
        function testCalc() {
            var t1 = performance.now();
            var r = arr.reduce(calc);
            console.log('testCalc(' + arr.length + '):time:' + (performance.now() - t1) + ', result:' + r);
        }

        //test calling calc() in the iframe
        function testCalcIFrame() {
            var t1 = performance.now();
            var r = arr.reduce(icalc);
            console.log('testCalcIFrame(' + arr.length + '):time:' + (performance.now() - t1) + ', result:' + r);
        }

        function testCalcAllIframe() {
            var arr2 = new Array(1000 * 1000);
            for (var i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++)
                arr2[i] = i;

            var t1 = performance.now();
            var r = arr2.reduce(calc);
            console.log('testCalcAllIframe(' + arr2.length + '):time:' + (performance.now() - t1) + ', result:' + r);
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

To try the test code, open the developer tool's console in your browser, and press "testCalcIFrame" to test calling a function in the iframe, and press "testCalc" to test calling a function in the main document.

Update: I tried injecting a script element into the iframe instead of using eval(), as suggested by
 Jan Dvorak:

```
//iwin.eval(...) replaced by:
var iscript = iwin.document.createElement('script');
iwin.document.body.appendChild(iscript);
iscript.textContent = calc.toString() + '\n' + testCalcAllIframe.toString();
```

However, the performace is almost the same as using eval().

Comment: If I had to guess I'd say it's due to the browsers constantly re-checking the security restrictions, while Chrome is able to optimise the checks away, only decompiling when the document origin changes.

Comment: Maybe the difference is due to `eval` being used. Try injecting a script element instead.

Comment: Hi Jan Dvorak, I tried injecting a script element instead of eval(), but it makes no significant difference.

Comment: Hi Jan Dvorak, isn't a one-pass security check good enough to enforce the same-origin policy? Although the base URI may be dynamicly changed by inserting a <base> element, the main document can still access its iframes' content if it could before the change.

Comment: [`document.domain`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.domain). 'nuff said.

Comment: also, test what happens when you inject/eval within the same frame

Comment: If I understand right, document.domain is used to relax same-origin policy, not to restrict it, so if an iframe is accessible at the beginning, it will be accessible for its life time. So, there is no need to make security check for each call across iframe boundery.

Comment: How to inject/eval within the same frame? By the may, I tried defining function calc() staticly in a html file referenced by the iframe, the performance data are largely the same as inject/eval.